# elasticsearch filter aggregation - multiple filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Using ElasticSearch aggregation to aggregate data on my documents.
so the aggregation request looks something like this

```
 {  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "terms":{  
                  "status":[  
                     "active",
                     "deleted"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "terms":{  
                  "address_ids":[  
                     4078,
                     4080
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggregations":{  
      "neighbourhoods":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"neighbourhoods",
            "size":100
         }
      },
      "budgets_stats":{  
         "filter":{  
            "range":{  
               "budget":{  
                  "lt":100000
               }
            }
         },
         "aggregations":{  
            "budget":{  
               "stats":{  
                  "field":"budget"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

i want to filter out documents that match ** budget lower than 100000 ** and add more filters to that specific aggregation. 
I cant add it to the query clause, because i have other aggregation in which i dont want these budget filters to apply.

I cant use the filters aggregation either because it creates a different bucket for each filter - instead of 1 bucket with all filters applied to it.

How can create a filter aggregation with more than 1 filter? lets say the other condition should be 
    "budgets_stats":{
             "filter":
                {
                   "range":{
                      "vip_budget":{
                         "gt":500
                      }
                   }
                }
          }

i have tried using Array but its not working.

`filter: [{:range=>{:budget=>{:lt=>100000}}}, {:range=>{:vip_budget=>{:gt=>500}}}]`

getting this error (using rails gems)

Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest Exception: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"**Expected [START_OBJECT] under [filter], but got a [START_ARRAY] in [budgets_stats]","line":1,"col":233}]**,"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Expected [START_OBJECT] under [filter], but got a [START_ARRAY] in [budgets_stats]","line":1,"col":233},"status":400}

Is this even possible? couldn't find a reference in the documentation of elastic / rails gems for elastic

Will appreciate any help,

Thanks

Comment: `filter` can't accept an array in ES's DSL. What you want is a bool filter where the `must` clause can accept multiple queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/bool-query.html

Comment: Something like this: `filter: {
    :bool=>{
        :must=>[
            {:range=>{:budget=>{:lt=>100000}}},
            {:range=>{:vip_budget=>{:gt=>500}}}
        ]
    }
}`

Comment: @wholevinski Appreciate the quick reply!
in the query part it does let me use array filter...
`{:filter=>
      [{:terms=>{:status=>["active", "dead"]}},
       {:term=>{:event=>4010}},
       {:terms=>{:address_ids=>[4078, 4080]}},
       {:range=>{:budget=>{:gte=>0, :lte=>99999999}}},
       {:term=>{:editors_pick=>true}}]`

Ill give what you said a try, although in the rails elasticsearch-dsl gem it doesnt really mention it 
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-dsl/Elasticsearch/DSL/Search/Aggregations/Filter

Comment: @wholevinski it worked!
thats the rails syntax if anyone needs it:
`filter(bool:{must:  [{range: {"#{this.budget}": {lt: 100000}}}, {range: {"#{this.budget}": {gt: 300}}}]   }) do
                aggregation :budget do
                  stats field: "#{this.budget}"
                end
              end`